# Optimization for function for pell numbers, Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I need to write a function for finding n-th Pell number.

This is recurrence relation for Pell numbers.

```
P[0]=0, P[1]=1
P[n+1] = 2P[n] + P[n-1]; n>=1;
```

I did that this way:

```
P[n_] :=
  If[n >= 1,
   Return[2*P[n - 1] + P[n - 2]]];
```

It worked, but it has to be optimized for n>=50 so those can be calculated in relatively short time, and this one doesn't work fast.

Comment: Search for memoization.

Comment: Even more optimal than @b.gatessucks suggestion, good though it is, would be to read the documentation on the `Fibonnacci` function, in particular that part which covers the 2-argument form of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is good. Or could do

```
pell[n_] = 
 RSolveValue[{p[n] == 2*p[n - 1] + p[n - 2], p[0] == 0, p[1] == 1}, 
  p[n], n]

(* Out[4308]= -(((1 - Sqrt[2])^n - (1 + Sqrt[2])^n)/(2 Sqrt[2])) *)
```

Or

```
pell2[n_] := MatrixPower[{{2, 1}, {1, 0}}, n, {0, 1}][[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are close formulas for all the Pell and Nacci numbers. Here is the close formula for the Pell numbers you are looking for:

```
from __future__ import division  #if you are using python 2.x
from math import sqrt

Pell = 1 + sqrt(2)
pell = 1 - sqrt(2)

for i in range(1,50):
    print (Pell**i - pell**i)/(Pell-pell)
```